# How to run code when cookie is added?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, cookies, facebook

So I have the code below, and its purpose is to prevent the Facebook for Woocommerce plugin from running the FB pixel until the necessary consent is given. It works to solve the problem in the sense that when a new page is loaded, if the cookie consent is given, it will load the Pixel.

My problem though is that the code does NOT run when someone hits the "accept cookies" button without refreshing the page. So is there any way to make the code below run when consent is given (ie, when the cookie is first added, without requiring you to refresh the page)?

```
add_filter( 'facebook_for_woocommerce_integration_pixel_enabled',
'checkStatisticsAccepted', 10, 1 );
function checkStatisticsAccepted() {
    if (isset($_COOKIE["CookieConsent"])) 
    { 
      switch ($_COOKIE["CookieConsent"])
      {
            case "-1":
                  //The user is not within a region that requires consent - all cookies are accepted
                  return true;
              
            default: //The user has given their consent 

                  //Read current user consent in encoded JavaScript format 
                  $valid_php_json = preg_replace('/\s*:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)([}\[,])/', ':"$1"$2', preg_replace('/([{\[,])\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?):/', '$1"$2":', str_replace("'", '"',stripslashes($_COOKIE["CookieConsent"])))); 
                  $CookieConsent = json_decode($valid_php_json); 

                  if (filter_var($CookieConsent->statistics, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN))
                  { 
                        return true;
                  } 
                  else 
                  { 
                        return false;
                 }
       }
    } 
    else 
        {
              return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: No, this is server side code so won't run without a refresh. If you do want to add the facebook pixel without a refresh I'd try and make an AJAX endpoint that generates it, and use that to load it into the page. Or try and include it on the page in an inactive state and only activate it when cookies are accepted, which you'd have to do in client side script too.

Comment: You would need to make an AJAX request to do that, but even then, this all needs to be done in javascript. Remember, WordPress is loaded from a blank slate on every request, there's no WordPress background task running on the server. When WordPress has finished serving a page, the process  ends and everything has to be loaded from scratch when the next request happens. By the time your user is presented with a consent screen, WP has already done its job and been cleaned up on the server, and the request/PHP has ended